# What online tools can I use for a text corpus search?

Tags: discussion, resource-request

Suppose I want to search for a certain word, expression or structure in the Latin literature.
What **online** tools can I use for such purposes?
Where can I find a large collection of Latin texts in easily searchable form?

To describe the source or tool, please answer at least these questions:

- How is the corpus limited? (Is it only classical Latin, for example?)
- What kinds of searches can be made?
- How can I link to a specific passage that I want to cite?
- Is it connected to some other tools (like a dictionary or a full text translation) that make usage easier?

**Please give only one tool per answer.**
If you want to propose several tools, give them in separate answers.

Comment: Please see my notice regarding **[Should we make Canonical Resource questions?](http://meta.latin.stackexchange.com/a/142/16)** These *list-of-resources* questions are starting to catch on here; unfortunately, Meta support is meant to ask about of the Q&A software works or questions about the content, administration, or community. We cannot allow this to become  secondary Q&A where you post Latin questions you wouldn't allow on the main site. The proper way to administer these questions is suggested in the post I linked. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

One good source of Latin texts is [The Latin Library](http://thelatinlibrary.com/).
It contains a large amount of Latin texts ranging from classical ancient authors to writers in the past few centuries.
The interface is very light and intuitive.

The library does not come with a search tool.
You can, however, use a Google search specialized to that site.
For example, searching for `site:thelatinlibrary.com "amicus meus"` produces a list of occurrences of the phrase *amicus meus* in Latin literature.
Searching is only as flexible as your external search engine is; looking for all possible declined forms of *amicus meus* at the same time seems impossible.

The top of many pages contains a list of links to numbered parts of the page.
There are also many numbers (such as verse numbers) that cannot be linked to but can help describe where to find the passage.
Sometimes there are no links but it is still possible to link to parts of a page; I know no better way to do this than to inspect the source code for `<a name="name_of_label">`.
This is how I found the link [to Tertullianus' work](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/tertullian/tertullian.apol.shtml#C47) for my answer to a [question about *non omnino*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/477/79).

The library does not link to any dictionary or other helpful tool.
It is just a collection of texts, that's all.
On the positive side, it is very light and easy to use.